# How to add new text file in zip file using ruby

Tags: ruby, zip

Is it possible to add a new text file in the zip file without extracting the zip file using ruby?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are you using a specific library? A quick google found me [this](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/blob/e5e3f97ec891cb596f1af8950fc9749c99b809e9/lib/zip/output_stream.rb), which looks to be what you're after?

Comment: If you find out that its working, consider asking the https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip people whether they would accept a change in their README that explains how to do what you want to achieve (and then ideally provide them the text).